# Connecting a Redhat virtual machine to the host NIC that uses network bonds

Tags: rhel, virtual-machine, network-interface

I'm running Redhat 6.6 on severs with multiple interfaces. And I am successfully using network bonds on the interfaces to connect with the different VLANs on the existing network.  The servers are working fine.

The problems start when I attempt to use the Redhat virtual manager to start an instance of a guest OS.  I need to run CentOS as the guest OS.  I can start the CentOS vm instance without issue, but I cannot get the networking to function properly.

NetworkManager is disabled on my Redhat server host.  The ifcfg-xxx files on the Redhat host are configured to use network bond0 and bond1 to manage the multiple IP addresses and they work as expected.

How do I set up the Redhat virtual machine network connections to use the network bonds of the host?  When I start the instance of CentOS, the guest OS cannot ping it's host, nor can the host ping the guest OS.  And yes, ICMP is turned on and allowed on our network.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have Redhat support I'd ask them :)